# From 1 to 3 controllers in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm new to angularJS so I'm still learning the "angular way" of doing things and therefore seek for advice.

I started building my login/register/forgotten_password views which now work perfectly fine. So the routing looks basically like this:

```
mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
   .when('/login',
   {
       controller: 'loginCtrl',
       templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
   })
   .when('/register',
   {
       controller: 'registerCtrl',
       templateUrl: 'views/register.html'
   })
   .when('/dashboard',
   {
       controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
       templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
   })
})
```

Now here's the problem and/or question I have :

After a successful login, you get redirected to the dashboard which gets loaded into `ng-view`. The dashboard is indeed the view but there should be more controllers and templates once you enter the app (sidebar, topbar, chat...).

How would you approach this ?

I also have a globalCtrl on the html element to handle other things, just in case that information might be helpful in any way.

Comment: I recommend the ui-router. It has awesome features like named views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't think in controllers anymore. Rather think in "components". There are lots of articles on the internet on how to learn this (better) approach. Here is one to start: [Refactoring Angular Apps to Component Style](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/10/18/refactoring-angular-apps-to-components.html)

**tl;dr;** Create a component (element directive) for every section/part of your view. In your case a `<dashboard>`, `<sidebar>`, `<topbar>`, ...

You can (and should) route to components! See this [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2627) for more information. Here is a "real life" example on how to achieve this: https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-ng1

Comment: OK, I do like this approach but is there a practical example somewhere ? I'm still reading the article, and my question would be: once I enter the dashboard with these 3 components, how do I handle the routing so that <dashboard> switches to <settings> for example ?

Comment: You could use nested states and child routes for that https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-%26-nested-views

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 0):

This is the con giving of using `$routeProvider` in Angular JS. When you use a `$routeProvider` to define routes in angular JS, a single route can only point to a single view and there is no concept of nested views using `$routeProvider`.

And when you talk about having more than one template inside the view, you are talking about having nested views inside a single view. Unfortunately Angular's `$routeProvider` doesn't provide that. But now comes the ui-router, which replace the concept of route with states. You can define multiple sub states in a state and each sub state can point to different template. Look at the following link and follow simple steps to power up views and nested views in your app.

[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)